# unit testing attributes dataannotations validator

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I am using DataAnnotations for my model validation

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MvcApplication2.Models
{
    public class Fiz
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [RegularExpression(".+@..+")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string adress { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string city { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string gold { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string father { get; set; }
    }
}

// test class
[TestMethod]
public void EmailRequired()
{
    var fiz = new Fiz 
    {

        Email = "exemple"
    };

    Assert.IsTrue(ValidateModel(fiz).Count > 0);
}

private IList<ValidationResult> ValidateModel(object model)
{
    var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
    var ctx = new ValidationContext(model, null, null);
    Validator.TryValidateObject(model, ctx, validationResults, true);
    return validationResults;
}
```

the problem that i want to test  just the Email  but in this case i have to give  a values to  fiz.Name;fiz.adress;.....

any solutions?
thinks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out AutoFixture

https://github.com/AutoFixture

It can hydrate your entities with data, so you only have to concern yourself with the properties that you want to test.

Great for creating your test entities in just a few lines of code

Comment: can you give me an exemple or a tutorial about that ?!

Comment: http://nikosbaxevanis.com/blog/2011/02/22/creating-test-fixtures-easily-with-autofixture/ shows the basics, it is really easy though.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to test that your data annotations are correctly placed, you need to provide data to every field (either manually or with some 3rd party tool). But hits might not be such a bad idea as you can create one test per entire object and assert on the contents of the `validationResults`;